# get iPhone latest models bottom height

Tags: ios, swift

I have function that suppose to calculate 1/3 of screen height. Here is the implementation:

```
struct Offsets {

  static let singlePixel = (1.0 / UIScreen.main.scale)
  static func  thirdScreenHeightExceptTabAndNavBar() -> CGFloat {
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    let screenHeightExceptStatusAndNavAndTabBar = screenHeight - Offsets.statusBarHeight() - Offsets.navBarHeight() - Offsets.tabBarHeight()
    return CGFloat(screenHeightExceptStatusAndNavAndTabBar / 3)

  }

  static func navigationAndStatusBarHeight() -> CGFloat{
    return Offsets.statusBarHeight() + Offsets.navBarHeight()
  }

  static func tabBarHeight() -> CGFloat {
    return UITabBarController().tabBar.frame.size.height
  }

  static func navBarHeight() -> CGFloat {
    return UINavigationController().navigationBar.frame.size.height
  }

  static func statusBarHeight() -> CGFloat {
    return UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
  }
}
```

As it prints out, tab bar height is 49, but, it look like distance from top of tab bar to bottom of device is bigger, there is screen.

[image]

How to measure this distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the `bottomInset` of the screen using `safeAreaInsets` of the `keyWindow` in `UIApplication's` `shared` instance.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    let bottom = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    print(bottom)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get offsets as like below. New notch displays using safeAreaLayout, so you can calculate from it.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
  let bottom = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
}
```

Comment: my class has no reference to view.

Comment: Try to get top view from window. Window is accessible from UIApplication